# Java web development bulk upload

Tags: java, file-upload, ftp

I will have to implement the possibility to upload multiple files (thousands) from a website.
I think I will use a FTP client, any suggestion or other idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Some more info would be helpful: what OS is the server on? Do you want to write something to do it automatically from time to time?

Comment: Do you want to bulk-upload or synchronize files? That makes quite difference with regard to efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to be doing this on a regular basis, you might want to take a look at [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). Unchanged files will not be transferred, saving you on time and bandwidth. You can also tunnel rsync through ssh if you need security.